# I am not understanding how WSDL and SOAP works, apparently

Tags: javascript, xml, api, soap, wsdl

I am not being able to make a SOAP API installed locally work. I have tried several frameworks (all of them for JS) and nothing. I am currently stuck in a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'description')`  when I send the post request with some numbers to add and can't figure out what is wrong with... whatever is wrong.

the server I made:

```
const soap = require('soap');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

// Define the service operations
const service = {
  CalculatorService: {
    CalculatorPortType: {
      AddOperation: function(args) {
        const result = args.num1 + args.num2;
        return { result: result };
      }
    }
  }
};

// Create the SOAP server
const xml = fs.readFileSync('calculator.wsdl', 'utf8');
const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.end('404: Not Found: ' + req.url);
});
server.listen(8000);
const srvr = soap.listen(server, '/calculator', service, xml, function () {
  console.log('asdasdasd');
});
srvr.log = function (type, data) {
  console.log(type);
  console.log(data);
  console.log(`\n\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n\n`);
}
console.log('SOAP server running at http://localhost:8000/calculator');
```

Any tip will be greatly appreciated!

I have tried some frameworks, I've tried inserting the WSDL as XML directly in a string in the code, I've tried asking GPT 3.5... nothing has solved my problem.

edit: The WSDL file I've got:

```
<definitions name="CalculatorService" targetNamespace="http://localhost:8000/calculator" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://localhost:8000/calculator">
      <element name="AddOperation">
        <complexType>
          <sequence>
            <element name="num1" type="int"/>
            <element name="num2" type="int"/>
          </sequence>
        </complexType>
      </element>
      <element name="AddResponse">
        <complexType>
          <sequence>
            <element name="result" type="int"/>
          </sequence>
        </complexType>
      </element>
    </schema>
  </types>

  <message name="AddRequestMessage">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:AddOperation"/>
  </message>
  <message name="AddResponseMessage">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:AddResponse"/>
  </message>

  <portType name="CalculatorPortType">
    <operation name="AddOperation">
      <input message="tns:AddRequestMessage"/>
      <output message="tns:AddResponseMessage"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>

  <binding name="CalculatorBinding" type="tns:CalculatorPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="AddOperation">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost:8000/calculator/AddOperation"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>

  <service name="CalculatorService">
    <port name="CalculatorPort" binding="tns:CalculatorBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8000/calculator"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: The xml is not valid.  It is missing the namespace for URL soap in five locations.  Here is one of them ` <soap:address location="http://localhost:8000/calculator"/>`

Comment: I am assuming you are thinking of five specific lines in the XML. I see it already is inside port, which is inside service. Where else should it go? Sorry but I am really lost and frustrated with this.
Any clarification as to why that tag has to go in other places is optional but would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get the xml?  You should report the error to the people who supplied you the xml.

Comment: I was just starting to use XMLs. You are right in that it is not valid, but I didn't know enough to realise.
I had downloaded it from some page and then edited it, so that could be a reason. I have already built the service I needed. Appreciate a lot your answer! Cheers.